# PHP: preg_match( )

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, special-characters

this is my first post in here, i tried to check around the forum but i'm quite confused... i'm trying to validate a first name, at the moment my code is like:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-ZÀÁÂÄÆÃÅĀàáâäæãåāÈÉÊËĒĖĘèéêëēėęÎÏÍĪĮÌîïíīįìÔÖÒÓŒØŌÕôöòóœøōõÛÜÙÚŪûüùúūŸÿŚŠßśšŁłŽŹŻžźżzÇĆČçćčÑŃñń]*$/u", $fname))
{echo 'error';}
```

as you can see i'm trying to include all the special characters with accents etc... well i have 2 problems... first i don't understand why i still get errors when i test a special character, it seems that only the range a-zA-Z works but i don't get where's my mistake...
and second, i feel a so dumb using such a long expression, so maybe somebody knows how to make this simple and shorter hopefully?

Comment: Don't validate names, just check that the string doesn't contain malicious code.

Comment: This is a bad idea. I once went to a site that insisted my email address was invalid because it wasn't validating '.co.uk' properly. There was no way I could use the site so I went elsewhere. I'd leave more quickly if someone told me my name was 'invalid'.

Comment: well proper email address validation is a good idea, but leaving names alone is also recomended

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only allow letters, from all scripts with various accents, it's pretty simple:

```
^\p{L}+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR4qT2/1). `\p{L}` means *any kind of letter from any language*.

**But this is a bad idea. Really.** Don't validate names because **you can't really assume anything**. Read this article: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) to know why.

Comment: This is really useful to know. Never used it before.

Comment: seems that preg_match("/^\p{L}+$/", $fname) still doesn't work, on the demo it does but not when i test it on my page... @lucas

Comment: @Massimiliano you have to escape the backslash when used in quotes... `preg_match("/^\\p{L}+$/", $fname)`

Comment: @peter doesn't work :-/ , i tried escaping the backslash too... i don't really understand where I'm wrong..

Comment: @Massimiliano try with single quotes: `preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/', $fname)`... I didn't do PHP for a long while now...

Comment: @peter i found the problem, i was sanitizing the variable $fname with the command html_entities( ) before passing it inside th preg_match() and for that reason those special characters were making troubles, removing the html_entities passage before t works great